# why I'm getting this error after executing 'gem install any_gem'?

Tags: ruby

I tried the following command:  gem install rgl
then I got the following error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (ArgumentError)
    wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

more info:
windows 10
ruby 2.5

Answer (score 1):

Being on windows, I have updated ruby and re-installed the ruby devkit for ruby version > 2
by running

```
choco install ruby2.devkit --force
choco upgrade ruby2.devkit
```

Then I opened a new cmd and the issue was gone.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I fount is to install ruby 2.4.4-2 with DevKit.